Is it possible to convert a Bézier curve to a NURBS curve while preserving the curve?
I'm interested in converting Bézier paths to their matching NURBS counterparts. I know how to change a curve's spline type from Bézier to NURBS, but that is not what I mean by this question as that doesn't preserve the path. I've included images to help describe my goal.
Go from this:

To this:

I hope I explained this clearly. I'd love a Blender native solution, but open to any addons (free or paid) that help me achieve this!

When you convert spline type from Bezier to NURBS, you can enable an option called "Handles" in the Adjust Last Operation panel:

